# Asignar valor a celda de fila de tabla

Tags: html, dom, html-tabla

Tengo la siguiente función que recupera la fila seleccionada de una tabla:

```
function cambios(){
    var tds = $(this).find('td');
}
```

Quiero modificar los valores de dicha fila y mostrarlos en la tabla, lo estaba realizando de esta manera pero no funciona:

```
tds[3].val("nuevoValor");
```

tambien:

```
$(tds[i]).html()='nuevoValor';
```

De esta forma también pero no sale, en este caso quiero cambiarle el valor a la tercera celda de esa fila:

```
$(tds[2]).html('45');
```

Me estoy basando de una función que use para recuperar datos de una fila y asignarlos a varios input pero ahora quiero modificar la fila de la tabla que selecciono.

La función es la siguiente

```
function alertas(){
        var tds = $(this).find('td');
        var array_valores =  Array();

        for(var i =  0; i < tds.length; i++){
            array_valores.push($(tds[i]).html());
        }
        $("#prod_codigo").val(array_valores[0].toString());
        $("#prod_descrip").val(array_valores[1].toString());
        $("#PROD_UNIDAD").val(array_valores[2].toString());
        $("#pu_cantidad").val(array_valores[3].toString());
        $("#pu_minimo").val(array_valores[4].toString());
        $("#pu_maximo").val(array_valores[5].toString());
        $("#pu_costo").val(array_valores[6].toString());
        $("#pu_precionormal").val(array_valores[7].toString());
        $("#pu_precioespecial").val(array_valores[8].toString());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`<td>` es una etiqueta "normal", no un `input` por tal motivo no podrás asignarle ningún valor por el medio `.val()`, y en tu segunda opción estás teniendo un problema de sintaxis.

```
$(tds[i]).html('nuevoValor');
```

Espero que te sirva, saludos !

Comment: pero al hacerlo de esta forma 'var tds = $(this).find('td');' puedo obtener todos los valores y los almaceno en la variable tds, como podria modificar el valor de las celdas de la fila en la tabla?

Comment: var tds = $(this).find('td'); -> eso te trae los td como elementos del dom, es decir te trae todo el elemento no solo su contenido y para modificar el contenido de un td es la línea $(tds[i]).html('nuevoValor');

Comment: ya lo hice pero no funciona

Comment: Edita tu pregunta, muestra todo el código de como lo estás haciendo, te sale algún error? cual es el comportamiento del código ?

Comment: ya añadí el código

Comment: Pero muestra la función completa, no por líneas

Comment: ya le añadi el codigo